# Trouble referring type list(object) variable from module directory using for_each into main dir

Tags: terraform

I have created a variable of type list(object) on a module directory. My goal is to call this variable under a different directory using a for_each loop. (Tree attached below)

```
.
├── main.tf
├── output.tf
└── proxmox-instance
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf
    ├── providers.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

The variable.tf file looks like this

```
variable "forwarded_ports" {
  description = "Your Template name - Will be cloned from this template"
  type = list(object({
    host_port  = number
    guest_port = number
  }))
  default = [{
    "host_port"  = 2222,
    "guest_port" = 22
  }]
}
```

While the ./proxmox-instance/main.tf looks like this

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = [for k in var.forwarded_ports : k]

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port                                                  # Custom Port for ingress connections
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```

**The issue occurs while trying to refer the code at the `forwarded_ports` section below**

```
module "instance" {
  source = "./proxmox-instance"

  vm_name       = "Terraform"
  template_name = "ubuntu-20.04"

  # cloud-init settings
  ipconfig0           = "ip=dhcp"
  cloud_init_user     = "ubuntu"
  cloud_init_password = "password"

  forwarded_ports = [
    {
      host_port  = 2222
      guest_port = 22
    },
    {
      host_port  = 5555
      guest_port = 22
    },
  ]
}
```

I've tried playing with the syntax abit and got different results

### Output 1/2

```
for_each = [for k in var.forwarded_ports : k]


│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on proxmox-instance\main.tf line 37, in resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front":
│   37:   for_each = [for k in var.forwarded_ports : k]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.forwarded_ports is list of object with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

### Output 2/2

```
for_each = toset([for k in var.forwarded_ports : k])


│ Error: Invalid for_each set argument
│ 
│   on proxmox-instance\main.tf line 37, in resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front":
│   37:   for_each = toset([for k in var.forwarded_ports : k])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.forwarded_ports is list of object with 2 elements
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forwarded_ports` is a list. `for_each` works with maps. You can easly convert list to map as follows:

```
 for_each = { for i,v in var.forwarded_ports : i => v}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are providing a variable of type `list(objects)` and you are trying to use a list with `for_each` (which error output shows you it is not possible) while it can work only with maps or sets. What you could try is the following:

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = { for i in var.forwarded_ports : i.host_port => {
    host_port  = i.host_port
    guest_port = i.guest_port
  } }

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port                                                  # Custom Port for ingress connections
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a `locals` block and create the map you want there:

```
locals {
  fowarded_ports = { for i in local.forwarded_ports : i.host_port => {
    host_port  = i.host_port
    guest_port = i.guest_port
  } }
}
```

And then in the resource block:

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = local.forwarded_ports

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port                                                  # Custom Port for ingress connections
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```